# Mysql, Insert new record into table B if foreign key exists in table A

Tags: mysql, select, insert, key

There are a few similar questions on here. None provide a solution. I would like to INSERT a **NEW** record into table **B**, but only if a foreign key exists in table **A**. To be clear, I do not wish to insert the result of a select. I just need to know that the foreign key exists.

```
INSERT INTO tableB (tableA_ID,code,notes,created) VALUES ('24','1','test',NOW())
        SELECT tableA_ID FROM tableA WHERE tableA_ID='24' AND owner_ID='9'
```

Clearly, the above does not work. But is this even possible? I want to insert the NEW data into tableB, only if the record for the row in tableA exists and belongs to owner_ID.

The queries I have seen so far relate to INSERTING the results from the SELECT query - I do not wish to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO tableB (tableA_ID,code,notes,created) 
SELECT id, code, notes, created
FROM ( SELECT '24' as id, '1' as code, 'test' as notes, NOW() as created) t
WHERE EXISTS 
(
   SELECT tableA_ID 
   FROM tableA 
   WHERE tableA_ID='24' AND owner_ID='9'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this results in an error 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('24','1','test',NOW()) ) t(....

Comment: @BernieDavies When I initially posted my answer I thought it was for SQL Server! Please check the edit I made.

Comment: Yes! Giorgos, that seems to work beautifully. Thank you. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a pretty much old answered question but it's highly ranked now in google search results and I think some addition may help someone in the future.

In some DB configuration, you may want to insert a row in a table that have two or more foreign keys. Let's say we have four tables in a chat application :
`Users`, `Threads`, `Thread_Users` and `Messages`

If we want a `User` to join  a `Thread` we'll want to insert a row in `Thread_Users` in wich have two foreign keys : `user_id`, `thread_id`.

Then, we can use a query like this, to insert if both foreign keys exists, and silently fail otherwise :

```
INSERT INTO `thread_users` (thread_id,user_id,status,creation_date)
SELECT 2,3,'pending',1601465161690 FROM (SELECT 1 as nb_threads, 1 as nb_users) as tmp 
WHERE tmp.nb_threads = (SELECT count(*) FROM `threads` WHERE threads.id = 2)
      AND tmp.nb_users = (SELECT count(*) FROM `users` WHERE users.id = 3)
```

It's a little verbose but it does the job pretty well.

Application-side, we just have to raise an error if affectedRows = 0 and maybe trying to see which of the keys doesn'nt exists. IMHO, it's a better way to do the job than to execute two SELECT queries and THEN execute the INSERT especially when an inexistent foreign key probability is very low.